# EditText field not appending text

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to Android. I am making a very simply **calculator**.
For the Plus button I've written code to getText from the `editText` field store it in an array index for later addition and then show the + sign to be appended so the user can see the operation.

But for the code posted below, everything else executes except it doesn't show the + sign appended to the `EditText` view.

```
button_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(lower_textfield.length() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write a number to add first",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = lower_textfield.getText().toString();
                arr[0] = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
                lower_textfield.append("+");
            }
        }
    });
```

Here `tmp` is String and `arr` is Int Array.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method

```
 append()
```

on the EditText object should must work.
Check the inputType of the EditText object.
May be mistakenly you've written  any numeric inputType like.

```
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

It should be

```
 android:inputType="none"
 OR
 android:inputType="text"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you're running on the GUI thread. Never touch GUI from a non-GUI thread.

If that isn't the problem, try this instead:

```
tmp = lower_textfield.getText().toString();
arr[0] = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
lower_textfield.setText(arr[0] + "+");
```

Comment: well that worked but can you explain why the append method didn't work. And I still don't have concept of GUI thread, i would like to see some references to that topic.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Read more about the UI thread here!
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

(Also, an upvote would be appreciated c:)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for now :)